# How to communicate local machine with webapplication(asp.net mvc) to trace individual machine mouse and keyboard

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, windows, websocket

Created a asp.net mvc framework application to track individual machines inactivity based on keyboard and mouse event. To achieve this, created web form desktop application and started websocket server

```
 wssv = new WebSocketServer(8181);
            wssv.AddWebSocketService<Echo>("/Echo");
            wssv.Start();
```

And from web application created websocket client.

```
private WebSocket _ws;
_ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:8181/Echo");
```

It is working fine when web application when running from iis of same machine with localhost. but not able to communicate when web application hosted in server.

Please provide the solution for communication between web application and other local windows machines

Comment: You can create a `asp.net core web api endpoint`  can call the endpoint from your windows service using `PeriodicTimer`.

Comment: Have you checked the firewall settings on the server to see if port 8181 has been whitelisted / allowed for communication?  The client machine may also need firewall reconfiguration but this is less likely: consider the following quote from a related post: *"By default, Windows Defender Firewall allows all outbound network traffic unless it matches a rule that prohibits the traffic."*